# Confidence interval using joint probability

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, joint-distribution

I'm working with this model, extracted from [1]:

$Z=(1+2\cdot X\cdot k+k^2)\cdot Y$

where $X$ and $Y>0$ are independent random variables, with known distributions, with means $\overline{X}=0$ and $\overline{Y}=1$, $k>0$ is a constant and $Z$ is calculated from experimental data.

$k$ is a kind of quality indicator, more specifically, a signal to noise ratio, and we need to find the value $Z_{min}(k)$ such that, if $Z>Z_{min}(k)$, then the quality is $\geq k$ with significance $\alpha$.

I don't have a solid statistics background and I didn't understand very well the approach used in [1]. To calculate $Z_{min}(k)$, the authors span all pairs $(x,y)$ such that $P(X>x)\cdot P(Y>y)=\alpha$ and calculate $Z_{min}(k)$ as the maximum value of $Z$ obtained from these pairs, i.e.:

$Z_{min}(k)=\max\{(1+2\cdot x\cdot k+k^2)\cdot y\ |\ P(X>x)\cdot P(Y>y)=\alpha\}$

I will call $(x_0,y_0)$ the pair where this maximum is achieved.

I don't understand why it works, because

$(X>x_0)\cap(Y>y_0)\implies Z>Z_{min}(k)$

but the inverse is not true. Then, finding $Z>Z_{min}(k)$ doesn't garantee that $X>x_0$ and $Y>y_0$, and, consequently, we can't say, **with significance $\alpha$**, that the quality is $\geq k$. What am I missing?

[1] https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6494805/

Comment: There's a lot here that is potentially confusing, and your reference is of little help because it's behind a paywall.  Since "k ... is a constant," how could it possibly have a "relationship" with $Z$??  How are $Y$ and $X$ determined, set, or observed?  What does it mean to be a "quality indicator" (and is this even important to know)?

Comment: X and Y distributions are set, theoretically determined. The word "relationship" is used by the authors, maybe because Z is an effort to estimate k (Z=1+k² on the average). You can ignore the information that k is a quality indicator. I just added this information because it seems to me it could help to understand the problem. More specifically, k is a signal to noise ratio.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer.